# Wrapping groups of input elements with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, wrapall

I have following code:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="field_1" value="on" /> Checkbox field_1
<input type="checkbox" name="field_1" value="off" /> Checkbox field_1


<input type="checkbox" name="field_2" value="on" /> Checkbox field_2
<input type="checkbox" name="field_2" value="off" /> Checkbox field_2
```

I need to wrap those elements with jQuery. It should look something like this:

```
<div>
<input type="checkbox" name="field_1" value="on" /> Checkbox field_1
<input type="checkbox" name="field_1" value="off" /> Checkbox field_1
</div>
<div>
<input type="checkbox" name="field_2" value="on" /> Checkbox field_2
<input type="checkbox" name="field_2" value="off" /> Checkbox field_2
</div>
```

I tried `$("input[name=field_1]".wrappAll("<div></div>")` but this will create a wrapper around the input elements but will not include the "Checkbox field_1...."

Comment: This might be a typo in copying to Stack Overflow, but it's `wrapAll()` (single-'P,' not double).

Comment: We know it's a question, and we know it's about jQuery. Can you improve on your question's title?

Answer (score 2):

I suggest that you should modify existing code to become something like this:

```
<label><input type="checkbox" name="field_1" value="on" /> Checkbox field_1</label>
<label><input type="checkbox" name="field_1" value="off" /> Checkbox field_1</label>

<label><input type="checkbox" name="field_2" value="on" /> Checkbox field_2</label>
<label><input type="checkbox" name="field_2" value="off" /> Checkbox field_2</label>
```

This will not only simplify your jQuery code (for jQuery is very good working with tag nodes and not that good working with text nodes) but also will improve accessibility since labels after checkboxes will become clickable.

Then in jQuery:

```
$('input[name="field_1"]').parent().wrapAll('<div/>')
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function wrapFieldSet(fields) {
    var wrapper = $('<div class="wrapper"></div>');
    fields.first().before(wrapper);
    fields.each(function() {
        var text = $(this.nextSibling);
        wrapper.append($(this)).append(text);
    });
}

wrapFieldSet($('input[name="field_1"]'));
```

Comment: You should also get int the habit of adding an id attribute to your input fields.

Comment: Updated to catch text nodes, too.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
var $div = $("<div />"), next, $this;

$("input[name=field_1]:first").before($div);
$("input[name=field_1]").each(function(){
  $this = $(this);
  next = $this.next();
  $div.append($this);
  $div.append(next)
});

$div = $("<div />");
```

Answer (score 0):

I was going to suggest wrapping Checkbox field_1 etc in a label, adding classes to each one and using this wrap example [jQuery API](http://api.jquery.com/wrap/) to accomplish your goal

i.e.

```
<input id="foo1" class="bar" type="checkbox" name="field_1" value="on" /> 
<label class="bar" for="foo1">Checkbox field_1</label>
<input id="foo2" class="bar" type="checkbox" name="field_1" value="off" />
<label class="bar" for="foo2">Checkbox field_1</label>
```

Then use

```
$('.bar').wrap('<div class="something" />');
```

Then do the second section with a different class

Answer (score -1):

it should work  :

```
$('input[name=field_1]').wrapAll('<div />');
```

[**Click Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/corotchi/BH5v3/)

Comment: Removing the text is not the same as wrapping it.

Comment: where do you see here removing text ?                           
$('input[name=field_1]').wrapAll('<div />');

Comment: Where do you see the text in your example? And where do you handle it in your code? You removed it from the problem entirely when you posted your answer.